# Mapping Postgres View in diesel Rust issues

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

So am trying to return a view from an already existing Postgres database using diesel orm. Here is the struct am trying to map

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable)]
#[diesel(table_name=WithdrawBalanceVw)]
pub struct WithdrawBalanceVw {
    //#[diesel(deserialize_as="AccountId")]
    pub account_id: Uuid,

    //#[diesel(deserialize_as="AccountNumber")]
    pub account_number: String,

    //#[diesel(deserialize_as="LedgerBalance")]
    pub ledger_balance: f64,

    //#[diesel(deserialize_as="AvailableBalance")]
    pub available_balance: f64,

    //#[diesel(deserialize_as="WithdrawalBalance")]
    pub withdrawal_balance: f64
}
```

I have added the table schema definition to `schema.rs`

```
diesel::table! {
    WithdrawBalanceVw {
        AccountId -> Uuid,
        AccountNumber -> Varchar,
        LedgerBalance -> Numeric,
        AvailableBalance -> Numeric,
        WithdrawableBalance -> Numeric
    }
}
```

and this

```
diesel::allow_tables_to_appear_in_same_query!(
    ...
    WithdrawBalanceVw,
);
```

and this is the code am trying to use to make the query

```
let mut connection: diesel::r2d2::PooledConnection<diesel::r2d2::ConnectionManager<PgConnection>> = get_connection()?;

        let query = "select * from public.\"WithdrawBalance_vw\" where \"AccountId\" = ? limit 1";

        let response = diesel::sql_query(query);
        let response = response.bind::<Uuid, _>(account_id)
            .get_result(&mut connection)?;
```

and my toml

```
...
diesel = { version = "2.0.0", features = ["postgres", "chrono", "serde_json", "uuid", "r2d2"] }
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
serde = { version = "1.0.137", features = ["serde_derive", "derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.103"
uuid = { version = "1.4.1", features = ["v4", "serde"] }
```

When I run `cargo check`, I get this

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `WithdrawBalanceVw: FromSqlRow<Untyped, Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/data/database_query_repository.rs:18:25
     |
18   |             .get_result(&mut connection)?;
     |              ---------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `FromSqlRow<Untyped, Pg>` is not implemented for `WithdrawBalanceVw`
     |              |
     |              required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `FromSqlRow<ST, DB>`:
               <(T1, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, Untyped), __DB>>
               <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T0) as FromSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST8, Untyped), __DB>>
             and 23 others
     = note: required for `Untyped` to implement `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<WithdrawBalanceVw, Pg>`
     = note: required for `query_builder::sql_query::UncheckedBind<SqlQuery, uuid::Uuid, diesel::sql_types::Uuid>` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>, WithdrawBalanceVw>`
note: required by a bound in `get_result`
    --> /Users/xxx/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-2.1.0/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1723:15
     |
1723 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `RunQueryDsl::get_result`
```

Am not particularly sure what am doing wrong/not doing at this point. Please any help/pointers would be extremely helpful as am newish to both rust and diesel. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [`QueryableByName`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/deserialize/trait.QueryableByName.html):

> Deserializes the result of a query constructed with `sql_query`.

This is a different trait because Diesel can take advantage of type-safety and usually deserialize rows faster using that static information, but for `Untyped` queries it needs to handle and deserialize from the row more dynamically. See docs for [`sql_query()`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/fn.sql_query.html).

Fortunately, it can be `#[derive]`'d. So your struct would just need to add it:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, Queryable, QueryableByName)] // <------
#[diesel(table_name = crate::schema::WithdrawBalanceVw)]
pub struct WithdrawBalanceVw {
    #[diesel(column_name = "AccountId")]
    pub account_id: Uuid,

    #[diesel(column_name = "AccountNumber")]
    pub account_number: String,

    #[diesel(column_name = "LedgerBalance")]
    pub ledger_balance: f64,

    #[diesel(column_name = "AvailableBalance")]
    pub available_balance: f64,

    #[diesel(column_name = "WithdrawableBalance")]
    pub withdrawal_balance: f64,
}
```

As shown I've also added attributes so the field names are aligned and expressed that the `WithdrawBalanceVw` defined by `table!` should *not* be in scope if you use the same name as your struct.

Comment: Thank you. I just added this, now am getting `ambiguous associated type`

Comment: @Cizaphil You get that error when both the declaration from `table!` and your `struct` are both in scope and have the same name. I recommend using `#[diesel(table_name = crate::schema::WithdrawBalanceVw)]` (or whatever path) instead of importing it. You'll also need to name your struct's fields to match your column names or use `#[diesel(column_name = "...")]` for each field.

Comment: @Cizaphil Your code has several other deficiencies: `f64` and `Numeric` are incompatible (need to use `BigDecimal` Rust type or `Double` SQL type) and your table declaration doesn't have an `id` or primary key specified. Here is a fully compiling example: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9712a0add4c1b6408acb879e39208d26).